# ? How can I list all files in directory or drive without using stream and sort it by creation date using just nio api in java

Tags: java, file, nio

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Explorateur {
    public void Fichiers(String chemin) throws IOException {
        Path disque=Paths.get(chemin);
        try (Stream<Path> paths=Files.walk(disque, Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                 .forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do it without using Stream and sort it by creation date using just NIO ?

At first I need to check if a specific file is there. The second function is to sort all files by creation date.

I think that I should return a collection of files and creation date then sort it.

Comment: If you want to avoid streams (why though?) you can use `walkFileTree` which takes a `FileVisitor` that's called for each file.

Comment: I agree with you @Joachim Sauer.using stream is the best way to have a clean code.But my problem is that I need to sort files by creation date and show just the five first ones.To do that. I think that I need to put the result of my function in a Hashmap as a key then putting a creation date using " attribute.BasicFileAttributes".What do you think ?if my idea is good how can apply it?

Answer (score 1):

Contains pre Java 8 code only.

```java
public class ListFile {
    private static List<File> list = new ArrayList<>();

    private static void traverse(File path) {
        if (path.isFile()) {
            list.add(path);
        }
        else if (path.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = path.listFiles();
            for (File f : files) {
                traverse(f);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("ARGS: <directory>");
        }
        else {
            File path = new File(args[0]);
            traverse(path);
            Comparator<File> comp = new Comparator<File>() {
                
                @Override
                public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                    if (f1 == null) {
                        if (f2 == null) {
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else {
                            return 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (f2 == null) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        else {
                            Path p1 = f1.toPath();
                            Path p2 = f2.toPath();
                            try {
                                FileTime ft1 = (FileTime) Files.getAttribute(p1, "creationTime");
                                FileTime ft2 = (FileTime) Files.getAttribute(p2, "creationTime");
                                return ft1.compareTo(ft2);
                            }
                            catch (IOException xIo) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(xIo);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            Collections.sort(list, comp);
            int count = 0;
            int limit = 5;
            for (File f : list) {
                Path p = f.toPath();
                try {
                    FileTime ft = (FileTime) Files.getAttribute(p, "creationTime");
                    System.out.printf("[%s] %s%n", ft, p);
                }
                catch (IOException xIo) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(xIo);
                }
                if (++count == limit) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT

As requested, using NIO classes only.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class ListFile {
    private static List<Path> lst = new ArrayList<>();

    private static void roam(Path path) throws IOException {
        if (Files.isRegularFile(path)) {
            lst.add(path);
        }
        else if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
            DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(path); // throws java.io.IOException
            Iterator<Path> iterator = ds.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                roam(iterator.next());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args - starting directory.
     *
     * @throws IOException  if fails to access directory.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("ARGS: <directory>");
        }
        else {
            Path p = Paths.get(args[0]);
            roam(p);
            Comparator<Path> comp = new Comparator<Path>() {
                
                @Override
                public int compare(Path p1, Path p2) {
                    if (p1 == null) {
                        if (p2 == null) {
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else {
                            return 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (p2 == null) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        else {
                            try {
                                FileTime ft1 = (FileTime) Files.getAttribute(p1, "creationTime");
                                FileTime ft2 = (FileTime) Files.getAttribute(p2, "creationTime");
                                return ft1.compareTo(ft2);
                            }
                            catch (IOException xIo) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(xIo);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            Collections.sort(lst, comp);
            int count = 0;
            int limit = 5;
            for (Path pth : lst) {
                try {
                    FileTime ft = (FileTime) Files.getAttribute(p, "creationTime");
                    System.out.printf("[%s] %s%n", ft, pth);
                }
                catch (IOException xIo) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(xIo);
                }
                if (++count == limit) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a nice code but you used java.io.File.listFiles() which I can't use .The code should be done using only nio api not io .In nio we have Files not File.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You just collect the `Stream` into a collection like `Set`, `SortedSet` or `List`:

```
TreeSet<Path> paths = Files.walk(path).collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
if (paths.contains(a)) {
  // checked for presence
}
// if you want to sort the files right away
List<File> files = Files.walk(path)
                        .map(Path::toFile)
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(File::lastModified))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I don't think creation date is something you can find from the file api.

Comment: But that actually *is:* using a stream.

Comment: OP wanted to use a collection of files then sort it. I interpret the question as "how do I get this list in some data structure other than stream", to which the answer is to collect() it into whichever collection fits your needs best.

Answer (score 0):

This example works using `FileVisitor`. It is longer than stream examples, but will be quicker on very large directory structures as `FileVisitor` provides BasicFileAttributes so avoids file IO calls in sort.

Plus you can sort by name, creation, modified times etc:

```
public class ExampleFileVisitor
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Path dir = Path.of(args[0]);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        HashMap<Path,BasicFileAttributes> pathAttrs = scan(dir);

        ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>(pathAttrs.keySet());
        Collections.sort(paths,  Comparator.comparing(p -> pathAttrs.get(p).lastModifiedTime()));
        // Collections.sort(paths,  Comparator.comparing(p -> pathAttrs.get(p).creationTime()));
        // Collections.sort(paths,  Comparator.comparing(Path::getFileName));

        List<Path> top5 = paths.subList(0, Math.min(5, paths.size()));
        long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println("DONE "+dir+" SIZE "+paths.size()+" in "+elapsed+"ms");
        for (Path f : top5)
            System.out.println("Found "+f);
    }

    private static HashMap<Path, BasicFileAttributes> scan(Path dir) throws IOException
    {
        HashMap<Path,BasicFileAttributes> pathAttrs = new HashMap<>();
        FileVisitor<Path> visitor = new FileVisitor<>() {
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException  {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                pathAttrs.put(file, attrs);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                throw exc;
            }
            public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        };
        //visitor = Delegate.create(visitor, FileVisitor.class);
        Files.walkFileTree(dir, visitor);
        return pathAttrs;
    }
}
```

I think you can tell I've been in lockdown too long.

Comment: And use `paths.contains(whatever)` or `pathAttrs.get(whatever) != null` to check for a specific path.

Comment: Thank you so  much @DuncG for your effort. You take time to print this code witch seems to long without Stream. But I think that you should write Path not var.

Comment: This code is for Java 10+. It should run with var replaced by Path if your Java is older.

Comment: Changed answer so no "var". You can uncomment lines for other sort parameters.