# How to find specific directory and its files according to the keyword passed in java and loading in memory approach

Tags: java, file

I have a project structure like below:

[image]

Now, my problem statement is I have to iterate resources folder, and given a key, I have to find that specific folder and its files.
For that, I have written a below code with the recursive approach but I am not getting the output as intended:

```
public class ConfigFileReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Print L");
        String path = "C:\\...\\ConfigFileReader\\src\\resources\\";
        //FileReader reader = new FileReader(path + "\\Encounter\\Encounter.properties");
        //Properties p = new Properties();
        //p.load(reader);
        File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();
        String resourceType = "Encounter";
        System.out.println(navigateDirectoriesAndFindTheFile(resourceType, files));
    }
    public static String navigateDirectoriesAndFindTheFile(String inputResourceString, File[] files) {
        String entirePathOfTheIntendedFile = "";
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                navigateDirectoriesAndFindTheFile(inputResourceString, file.listFiles());
                System.out.println("Directory: " + file.getName());
                if (file.getName().startsWith(inputResourceString)) {
                    entirePathOfTheIntendedFile = file.getPath();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.print("Inside...");
                entirePathOfTheIntendedFile = file.getPath();

            }
        }
        return entirePathOfTheIntendedFile;
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]
The output should return `C:\....\Encounter\Encounter.properties` as the path.
First of all, if it finds the string while traversing it should return the file inside that folder and without navigating the further part as well as what is the best way to iterate over suppose `1k` files because every time I can't follow this method because it doesn't seem an effective way of doing it. So, how can I use an in-memory approach for this problem? Please guide me through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check the output of recursive call and pass that back when a match is found.

Always use `File` or `Path` to handle filenames.

Assuming that I've understood the logic of the search, try this which scans for files of form XXX\XXXyyyy

```
public class ConfigReader
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Print L");
        File path = new File(args[0]).getAbsoluteFile();
        String resourceType = "Encounter";
        System.out.println(navigateDirectoriesAndFindTheFile(resourceType, path));
    }
    public static File navigateDirectoriesAndFindTheFile(String inputResourceString, File path) {
        File[] files = path.listFiles();
        File found = null;
        for (int i = 0; found == null && files != null && i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                found = navigateDirectoriesAndFindTheFile(inputResourceString, file);
            } else if (file.getName().startsWith(inputResourceString) && file.getParentFile().getName().equals(inputResourceString)) {
                found = file;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
}
```

If this is slow especially for 1K of files re-write with `Files.walkFileTree` which would be much faster than `File.list()` in recursion.

Comment: Yeah, this solves my problem and I have accepted your answer. Also as the title of the problem says that is there any way to load the entire resource folder in memory so that the next time I need to read some file I ll just pick it from the cache. Can you just suggest me some link or some concept that I can go through since I am new to Java

Comment: I did add an example NIO file scan for another answer. See `ExampleFileVisitor.scan()` method in my answer further down  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62642962/how-can-i-list-all-files-in-directory-or-drive-without-using-stream-and-sort-i/62656900#62656900]. It will give you back a map of Path to attribute info but is easy to adapt to store whatever details of the files it finds.

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot buddy. I understood where I went wrong. Also, I will walkthrough your links. You made my day :)